# Sending HTTP requests with VBA from Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, httprequest

I am trying to send data from a Word document to a web page. I have found some code, pasted it into a new module, and saved it. When I run it I get "compile error, user defined type not defined"

My code:

```
Sub http()

  Dim MyRequest As New WinHttpRequest

    MyRequest.Open "GET", _
    "http://www.google.com"

    ' Send Request.
    MyRequest.Send

    'And we get this response
    MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A potential alternative to avoid having to select the library is to use an object i.e.

```
Sub http()
Dim MyRequest As Object

    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", _
    "http://www.google.com"

    ' Send Request.
    MyRequest.Send

    'And we get this response
    MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 22):

You need to set a reference to Microsoft WinHTTP Services in your VBA Project (Tools -> References).

Here's what it would look like:
[image]

Also, you can read more about the Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: When in my visual basic edit screen the tools>references menu command is greyed out.

Comment: @Saul: This usually means that code or the debugger is still running. Try clicking Run->Reset and then after that Tools>References.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change your references (Tools=>References in the code window). Look for `Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1` (or newer) and tick the box. If you are using Vista and office 2007, you may also need to register it first. Open a command window as administrartor and paste:

```
>regsvr32.exe "c:\windows\system32\winhttp.dll"
```

It should say if it works.