# how to send a HTTP Post in (vb mac excel 2011), and read the HTTP response?

Tags: vb.net, excel, http, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending http requests with VBA from Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119207/sending-http-requests-with-vba-from-word)

how to send a HTTP Post in (vb mac office excel 2011), and read the HTTP response ?
and please provide clear answers, I am new in vb.

not windows office, mac office 2011 !

thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [link to a similar question answered in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119207/sending-http-requests-with-vba-from-word). Code pasted here is from that link.

```
Sub http()
Dim MyRequest As Object

    Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    MyRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com"

    ' Send Request.
    MyRequest.Send

    'And we get this response
    MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you still need more advice.

Comment: yes this works, but only on the windows.
I need help with MAC office excel 2011, not windows office.
but thanks anyway Uwe Keim !

Comment: Johan, I apologize, I saw "mac" in your title and assumed "macro".  Here is another way, less elegant; but cross-platform it would appear.  [Alternate method on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158633/how-can-i-send-an-http-post-request-to-a-server-from-excel-using-vba)

Comment: I've already tried it, but both
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
and
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
gives me a runtime error 429,activex component can't create object

Comment: ops wait, I tried the wrong code : )

Comment: it work!
thanks Donny McCoy 3! write solution, and I'll mark it as answer for you.
I want the thread to be clear for others :)

Comment: How did you add the references to the project? I don't see WinHttpRequest on OSX