# VBA IE approve download in dialog window

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, download

Attempting to download data using a link to a file. IE opens and navigates to the file but a popup window asks me to open the file. I need to click this open button. Requesting help with navigating the pop up. Here is my code thus far:

```
Sub GetData()

Const cURL = "http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/ukinf05.xlsx"

Dim IE As InternetExplorer

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate cURL


End Sub
```

Comment: Use IE's developer tools to locate the `open` button's element id or name and set an object reference to it, which you can then click on.  A very quick search of this site (or Google) will give you hundreds of examples

Comment: If you have a URL that points directly to the file, using the API is much, much easier than automating IE.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26186347/4088852).

Comment: @Comintern Unfortunately I have tried codes like these and get the same "Unable to download the file, or the source URL doesn't exist" message. Despite this being a valid link.

Comment: @Dave The code I am using only opens the download window and even when IE.Visible=True  only the download window can be seen. Thus I do not have ability to open developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

As @Comintern had suggested, and with a little checking on [this blog entry by SiddarthRout](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/23/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window/)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> URL of the Path
    strURL = "http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/ukinf05.xlsx"
    '~~> Destination for the file
    strPath = "C:\temp\ukinf05.xlsx"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)

    If Ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to download the file"
    End If
End Sub
```

The end result I got was the file, correctly in my `C:\temp\` folder.