# Download file from website hyperlink in outlook

Tags: vba, csv, google-chrome, outlook, download

So I used the following code to open a Hyperlink from an email. This hyperlink opens the webpage and opens the download window to choose where to download a CSV and with what name (all of this is in Chrome). I want to be able to choose where said file will be downloaded and with what name. I would really appreciate the help :)

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long

Public Sub OpenLinks(olMail As Outlook.MailItem)

 Dim Reg1 As RegExp
 Dim M1 As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match
 Dim strURL As String
 Dim lSuccess As Long

Set Reg1 = New RegExp

With Reg1
 .Pattern = "(https?[:]//([0-9a-z=\?:/\.&-^!#$%;_])*)>"
 .Global = False
 .IgnoreCase = True
 End With

If Reg1.Test(olMail.Body) Then

Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
 For Each M In M1
   strURL = M.SubMatches(0)
   Debug.Print strURL

lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", strURL)

  Next
  End If

Set Reg1 = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

I've looked in other sites, but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Is this useful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704281/vba-go-to-website-and-download-file-from-save-prompt

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur It looks great, the issue is that the hyperlink opens in my chrome browser directly, once I tried to use it, it did nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the following ways:

1. Use Windows API, see the `URLDownloadToFile` function:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Public Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
Dim lngRetVal As Long
lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
If lngRetVal = 0 Then 
    If Dir(LocalFileName) <> vbNullString Then 
        DownloadFile = True
    End If
End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
If Not DownloadFile("http://www.test.come", "c:\\file.doc") Then
    MsgBox "Unable to download the file, or the source URL doesn't exist."
End If
End Sub
```

2. Click buttons programmatically using Windows API functions, see [VBA - Go to website and download file from save prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704281/vba-go-to-website-and-download-file-from-save-prompt) for more infromation.